# Cast a List<> in java?

Tags: java

Hi is it possible to cast a List?

i have an abstract class that has a method that takes some sort of List<>, iterate through it in a for loop getting each object in that list and calling the insertItem abstract method that is implemented by the sub class to basically pull out the proper data in the items and then finaly inserting them into a database table.

here is the super class method:

```
protected void insertAllItemsToDb(List<Object> items, String table) {
        // open db and table

        database().beginTransaction();
        // clear all data from table
        clearTable(table);
        // call a insert statement to insert each column from an item
        for (Object object : items) {
            insertItem(object, table);
        }
        // close db
        database().endTransaction();
        database().close();
    }
```

In the subclass here is one of the override methods: Which i am able to cast the object fine here.

```
  @Override
    protected void insertItem(Object object, String table) {

        CalendarEventItem item = (CalendarEventItem) object;
        eventItemValue = new ContentValues();

        eventItemValue.put(LABEL_EVENTS_TITLE, item.getEventTitle());
        eventItemValue.put(LABEL_EVENTS_LOCATION, item.getEventLocation());
        eventItemValue.put(LABEL_EVENTS_DATE, item.getEventStartTime()
                .getDate());
        eventItemValue.put(LABEL_EVENTS_TIME, item.getEventStartTime()
                .getTime());
        eventItemValue.put(LABEL_EVENTS_TIMEZONE, item.getEventStartTime()
                .getTimeZone());

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME_EVENTS, null, eventItemValue);

    }
```

i then call that method from the superclass using this:

```
events =  (List<CalendarEventItem>) items;
        insertAllItemsToDb(events, TABLE_NAME_EVENTS);
```

But i recieve a compile error saying you cant cast it. Any ideas on how i can achieve this without having to duplicate the same steps and code you see inside the insertAllItemsToDb()

Comment: never declare a generic as `<Object>`, if the type is unknown use `<?>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use a Type parameter

Add a generic Parameter to the abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>{

    protected abstract void insertItem(T object, String table);

    protected void insertAllItemsToDb(List<T> items, String table) {
        //...
        for (T object : items) {
            insertItem(object, table);
        }
        //...
    }

}
```

Now you don't need any casting, a child class just has to use the correct type:

```
public class FooBar extends BaseClass<Phleem>{
    protected void insertItem(Phleem object, String table){
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a better solution that just accepting a wildcarded list.  It avoids any casting, and basically guarantees type safety if the class is used in a parameterized manner.

Comment: What does T mean? can i specify any Letter their? say if i want to handle multiple generics, do i do something like  BaseClass<A, B, C> and in the sub class, public class Sub extends BaseClass<customer, product, order> ?

Comment: T is a type variable. You can write any letter, even combinations like T1, T2, T3. But the conventions can be found here (end of page):  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html

Comment: But yes, this works: `BaseClass<A, B, C>` and in the sub class, `public class Sub extends BaseClass<Customer, Product, Order>`

Answer (score 5):

A `List<Object>` is **not** a `List<CalendarEventItem>`, so the compiler is right that they aren't castable.  For a quick reason why, here's an example:

```
final List<Object> listOne = new ArrayList<Object>();
listOne.add("Hello World");

final List<CalendarEventItem> listTwo = new ArrayList<CalendarEventItem>();
listTwo.addAll(listOne); // Correctly disallowed by compiler

// This is what you're trying to do
List<CalendarEventItem> sneakyList = (List<CalendarEventItem>)listOne;
listTwo.addAll(sneakyList);
```

So casting between two incompatible types is disallowed because it would destroy the type-safety guarantees.

You almost certainly want to be declaring your `insertAllItemsToDb` method to take a `List<?>` rather than a `List<Object>`, since you don't care what the element type is so long as it's a subclass of Object (which is trivially true).

This should prevent you having to cast between inconvertible types, and is generally much nicer to work with.

For more information take a look at the Wildcard Bounds section of Angelika Langer's excellent [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html).  In fact, you should probably look over the whole thing if you haven't already.  The general principle to take away is that in *most* cases you should likely use wildcards on collections used for method arguments - the only time you wouldn't is if you both read from and write to the collection (which is actually surprisingly rare).

Comment: ok mate i tried List<?>, no compile errors but i get a warning saying Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#1-of ?> to List<CalendarEventItem>

Comment: Nooo, you don't need to cast at all.  **No casts** - that was the point of this. :-)  Just change the signature of `insertAllItemsToDb` and you should be good to pass in `items` as-is, without casting.

Comment: In fact in general, if you're using generics *and* casting, then you've done something wrong as the point of generics is to make things compile-time checkable without casts.  (Or you've come up against the limitations of the Java implementation, which is possible in some situations, but certainly not the case here).

Answer (score 0):

You could also just declare the method parameter as a regular list and then cast it to whatever generic list you want inside the method, ie your method would be `protected void insertAllItemsToDb(List items, String table)` and the first line you would cast it: `List<CalendarEventItem> newItems = (List<CalendarEventItem>) items`... of course implementing whatever type of checking/error catching that you should when doing such a thing.